# React native re render all components including child

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native

I want to rerender some specific child components when redux state has changed so that how to solve this problem

here is my code:

```
    <ItemMiniCard
  itemName={prop.item}
  price={prop.price}
  onPressAdd={() => { this.props.addCartItem(prop.id) }}
  onPressRemove={() => { this.props.removeCartItem(prop.id) }}
  />
```

in this Item Mini Card has some other child components

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 5 }}>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.itemText, { padding: 0 }]}>{itemName}</Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.descriptionText, { padding: 0 }]}>Delicius food rice and curry tasty food</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.priceTextBold, { padding: 0 }]}>LKR {price} {count} </Text>

            {count == 0 &&
                <Cbutton
                    title='Add +'
                    style={{ width: 52, height: 22 }}
                    onPress={onPressAdd}
                />
            }

            {count > 0 &&
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Cbutton
                    title='+'
                    style={{ width: 30, height: 20 }}
                    onPress={onPressAdd}
                />
                <View style={{marginLeft:3,marginRight:3}}>
                    <Text>{count}</Text>
                </View>
                <Cbutton
                    title='-'
                    style={{ width: 30, height: 20 }}
                    onPress={onPressRemove}
                />
            </View>
            }

        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

here when I add to cart product whole components getting re render how to prevent to re render whole components

Comment: If you use `ItemMiniCard ` in a list, have you tried setting `key`?

Comment: i am not add ItemMiniCard in a list

Comment: if i add ItemMiniCard in a list may this problem can solve?

Comment: Actually adding `key` when you have children of same type help to not rerender the children if data is not changed.

Comment: And you can use React's `shouldComponentUpdate` to specify when you want the component to render.

Comment: how to specify particular component to re render in shouldComponentUpdate ?

Comment: Please refer to react's documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent whole components from getting re-render, you can use PureComponent in react.

```
class Greeting extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

By default, rendering in a single component causes all of its sub-components to render also. Even if their props haven’t changed, but React.PureComponent implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison.

[Check official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to handle props or state to re-render the component

Example if you only want re-render screen when `count` or `price` change:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   if (nextProps.price !== this.props.price ||
       nextProps.count !== this.props.count) 
       return true;
   return false
}
```